# Convert.ChangeType() Returns incorrect value

Tags: arrays, vb.net, cnc

I've got a class that parses a CNC file, but I'm having difficulties with trailing "words" on each line of the file.

My code parses all leading "words" until it reaches the final word. It's most noticeable when parsing "Z" values or other Double type values. I've debugged it enough to notice that it successfully parses the numerical value just as it does with "X" and "Y" values, but it doesn't seem to successfully convert it to double. Is there an issue with a character I'm missing or something?

Here's my code:

```
    If IO.File.Exists("Some GCode File.eia") Then
        Dim sr As New IO.StreamReader("Some GCode File.eia")
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        'Read text file
        Do While Not sr.EndOfStream
            'Get the words in the line
            Dim words() As String = sr.ReadLine.Split(" ")
            'iterate through each word
            For i = 0 To words.Length - 1 Step 1
                'iterate through each "registered" keyword. Handled earlier in program
                For Each cmd As String In _registeredCmds.Keys
                    'if current word resembles keyword then process
                    If words(i) Like cmd & "*" Then
                        _commands.Add(i, _registeredCmds(cmd))
                        'Double check availability of a Type to convert to
                        If Not IsNothing(_commands(i).DataType) Then
                            'Verify enum ScopeType exists
                            If Not IsNothing(_commands(i).Scope) Then
                                'If ScopeType is modal then just set it to True. I'll fix later
                                If _commands(i).Scope = ScopeType.Modal Then
                                    _commands(i).DataValue = True
                                Else
                                    'Catch errors in conversion
                                    Try
                                        'Get the value of the gcode command by removing the "registered" keyword from the string
                                        Dim strTemp As String = words(i).Remove(0, words(i).IndexOf(_commands(i).Key) + _commands(i).Key.Length)
                                        'Save the parsed value into an Object type in another class
                                        _commands(i).DataValue = Convert.ChangeType(strTemp, _commands(i).DataType)
                                    Catch ex As Exception
                                        'Log(vbTab & "Error:" & ex.Message)
                                    End Try
                                End If
                            Else
                                'Log(vbTab & "Command scope is null")
                            End If
                        Else
                            'Log(vbTab & "Command datatype is null")
                        End If
                        Continue For
                    End If
                Next
            Next
            i += 1
        Loop
    Else
        Throw New ApplicationException("FilePath provided does not exist! FilePath Provided:'Some GCode File.eia'")
    End If
```

Here's an example of the GCode:

```
    N2930 X-.2187 Y-1.2378 Z-.0135
    N2940 X-.2195 Y-1.2434 Z-.0121
    N2950 X-.2187 Y-1.249 Z-.0108
    N2960 X-.2164 Y-1.2542 Z-.0096
    N2970 X-.2125 Y-1.2585 Z-.0086
    N2980 X-.207 Y-1.2613 Z-.0079
    N2990 X-.2 Y-1.2624 Z-.0076
    N3000 X0.
    N3010 X12.
    N3020 X24.
    N3030 X24.2
    N3040 X24.2072 Y-1.2635 Z-.0075
    N3050 X24.2127 Y-1.2665 Z-.0071
    N3060 X24.2167 Y-1.2709 Z-.0064
    N3070 X24.2191 Y-1.2763 Z-.0057
    N3080 X24.2199 Y-1.2821 Z-.0048
    N3090 X24.2191 Y-1.2879 Z-.004
    N3100 X24.2167 Y-1.2933 Z-.0032
    N3110 X24.2127 Y-1.2977 Z-.0026
    N3120 X24.2072 Y-1.3007 Z-.0021
    N3130 X24.2 Y-1.3018 Z-.002
    N3140 X24.
    N3150 X12.
    N3160 X0.
    N3170 X-.2
    N3180 X-.2074 Y-1.3029 Z-.0019
    N3190 X-.2131 Y-1.306 Z-.0018
    N3200 X-.2172 Y-1.3106 Z-.0016
    N3210 X-.2196 Y-1.3161 Z-.0013
    N3220 X-.2204 Y-1.3222 Z-.001
    N3230 X-.2196 Y-1.3282 Z-.0007
    N3240 X-.2172 Y-1.3338 Z-.0004
    N3250 X-.2131 Y-1.3384 Z-.0002
    N3260 X-.2074 Y-1.3415 Z-.0001
    N3270 X-.2 Y-1.3426 Z0.
    N3280 X0.
    N3290 X12.
    N3300 X24.
    N3310 X24.2
    N3320 G0 Z.1
    N3330 Z1.0
    N3340 G91 G28 Z0.0
    N3350 G90
```

With regard to the sample CNC code above, you'll notice that X and Y commands with a trailing Z command parse correctly.

**EDIT**
Per comment, here is a breakdown of _commands()
`_commands = SortedList(Of Integer, Command)`
Command is a class with the following properties:

- **Scope** as *Enum ScopeType*
- **Name** as *String*
- **Key** as *String*
- **DataType** as *Type*
- **DataValue** as *Object*

**EDIT: Solution!**
Figured out what was wrong. The arrays that make up the construction of the classes were essentially being passed a reference to the "registered" array of objects from the `Command` class. Therefore every time I parsed the value out of the "word" each line, I was overwriting the `DataValue` in the `Command` object.

The solution was to declare a new 'Command' object with every parse and append it to the proper array.

Here's my short hand:

```
...
For I = 0 To words.Length - 1 Step 1
  'iterate through each "registered" keyword. Handled earlier in program
  For Each cmd as String in _registeredCmds.Keys
    'if current word resembles keyword then process
    If words(I) Like cmd & "*" Then
      'NEW!!! Declare unassigned Command object
      Dim com As Command
      ' ****** New elongated logic double checking existence of values.....
      If _registeredCmds.Keys.Scope = ScopeType.Modal Then
        'assign Command object to previously declared variable com
        com = New Command()'There's technically passing arguments now to ensure items are transferred
      Else
        'Parse and pass DataValue from this word
        com = New Command()'There's technically passing arguments now to ensure items are transferred
      End If
      'New sub to add Command object to local array
      Add(com)
      Continue For
    End If
  Next
Next
...
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing some input data, or what `_commands(x).DataType` is, but `System.Convert.ChangeType()` returns `Object` which might not be what you want.  I'd use a generic to convert.

Comment: I'll add the breakdown of class Command